# html li style with css

Tags: html, css, list, block

this is my page:
http://bit.ly/Ti6Ptr

I would change this block style from 
[image]

to
[image]

How I have to do in my css?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is not a code factory. Please state what you have tried and what your actual issues with your approach are.

Comment: @HolgerJust He linked to the site with the code. I missed it too at first.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Linking to a full website doesn't qualify as an accurate problem description. Please refer to http://whathaveyoutried.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `width: 190px;` to you css selector `.liRecentPost a`

This is how it will look

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be for you to set the size of the div elements containing the text. Then the text will automatically flow to the next line when needed.

```
.imageText
{
    width:someWidth;
}

<img ... />
<div class="imageText">

</div>
```

Comment: but I have a div->ul->li->a->img

Comment: Why don't you put the text in a div element with a class so that you do not need to hardcode in the style for every span element? I will put some code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without html and css isn't easy but I think that in you text ("li" or "p") you have to set a width and display block and insert into a div to align all image
example:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="firstCol">
    <img src="img/yourimage.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="secondCol">
    <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.block{
   width:600px;
height:auto;
float:left;
}
    .firstCol{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    .secondCol{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }
    .text{
    width:300px;
    display:block
    }
```

N.B. the dimension is not real is only an example

Answer (score 0):

just add little css to your li

```
#recent_posts .ulRecentPost .liRecentPost  {width:200px; padding:5px;}
```